# ¿Cómo hago para setear un archivo .xml como background desde mi clase Java en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para configurar un archivo .xml (`button_rounded.xml`) a un botón desde mi clase java. La idea es que este botón tenga las propiedades que especifico en este archivo .xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
</shape>
```

Nota: Por defecto yo ya tengo establecido este mismo botón con la propiedad radius=16dp. El problema es que si yo le asigno que cambie solo de color (desde Java con el método `setBackgroundColor()`) cuando sucede un evento, se me cambia también los bordes del botón, y yo quiero que siga con la propiedad que había definido. Gracias.

Comment: Hola Lucas. Podrías explicar un poco más a fondo lo que estás intentando hacer? Te comento que para usar un archivo .XML desde tu clase Java debes hacerlo de esta manera `myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_rounded)` que en este caso es el nombre del archivo que creaste en la carpeta `drawable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Como puedo hacer para configurar un archivo .xml (button_rounded.xml)
>   a un botón desde mi clase java?.

Tu archivo `button_rounded.xml` que contiene un `Shape` debe ser guardado dentro del directorio `/drawable`

Para asignarlo a tu botón simplemente usa el método setBackgroundResource() del botón:

```
boton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_rounded);
```

> El problema es que si yo le asigno que cambie solo de color (desde
>   Java con el método setBackgroundColor()) cuando sucede un evento, se
>   me cambia también los bordes del botón, y yo quiero que siga con la
>   propiedad que había definido.

**En este caso al usar el método `setBackgroundColor()` si deseas que se mantengan las mismas propiedades al botón la única forma es que el archivo `button_rounded.xml` contenga estas propiedades.**

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funciona a la perfección :D

Comment: Excelente @Lucas Saludos.